# Determine if requested url is a Controller method with a return type of ViewResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to handle a returnUrl string after login request such that:

```
if (returnUrl is pointing to a ViewResult)
    proceed to the requested destination 
else
    Redirect to home
```

How do I determine if the url is pointing to a controller method with a return [type of ViewResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewresult(v=vs.118).aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I determine if the url is pointing to a controller method with a return type of ViewResult?

First, this is not a good idea.  If a result of a method is `ActionResult` you can not ever 100% know if the result is a `ViewResult`, because someone could change it.

If you are really determined to do this, then every return value on every controller would *have* to be `ViewResult`.  Then what you can do is create a custom [AuthorizationAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) which could then determine if the user is logged in, if the ReturnUrl is populated (or some other flag) and then using reflection (which is not great for performance, but it's only on sign-in so thats mostly ok) to determine the method's return type.

> I don't see why "every return value on every controller would have to be ViewResult."

Because if you don't do this, **you cannot guarantee** a method with a return type of `ActionResult` is a `ViewResult`.

[DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OsWaAn)

using System;

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var result = typeof(TestController).GetMethod("MyMethod").ReturnType;

        Console.WriteLine("TestController:MyMethod returns {0}", result.Name);
    }

    public class TestController
    {
        public ActionResult MyMethod()
        {
            return new ViewResult();
        }
    }

    // mocking System.Web.Mvc
    public abstract class ActionResult { }
    public class ViewResult : ActionResult { }
    public class JsonResult : ActionResult { }
}
```

Result

> TestController:MyMethod returns ActionResult

Someone changes `new ViewResult()` to `Json(myModel)` you can't detect the change through reflection.

Comment: I don't see why "every return value on every controller would have to be ViewResult." ViewResult is reserved in the application for returning full views with layouts while other ActionResult methods are for third party callbacks or Ajax calls that usually return PartialViews.